# How I get the clear button more on the right side?

Tags: ios, tableview, accessoryview

I add a UITextField to a UITableViewCell as a AccessoryView. I'd like a clear button at the end of the textfield. Now it looks like this:

http://twitpic.com/43mzwu

I think the clear button doesn't look good. I think it should be more on the right site. But now I found no solution to get the button more on the right side. Do you have any solution for my problem.

(Sorry for my bad english, I'm no native.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclass UITextfield and implement clearButtonRectForBounds:. You can refer to the iOS Reference Library for more details on [UITextFields](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006888-CH3-SW38).